# How to test eventListeners on input field and mock value using Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm pretty new with unit testing and would like to dive into testing, mostly testing eventListeners.

I'm trying to test if the value of an input text field matches the values in a mock array, as in simulating the user typing and returning a list of suggestions.

Here's my code:

```
const mockResultsData = [
    'Paris',
    'Lisbon',
    'Madrid',
    'Milan',
    'Malta',
];

let spy;
beforeAll(() => {
    spy = jest.spyOn(document, 'addEventListener');
});

describe("Check if user input value contains results", () => {
    let mockElement;
    beforeAll(() => {
        //create the mock element
        mockElement = document.createElement('input');
        document.body.appendChild(mockElement);
        spy.mockReturnValue(mockElement.value = 'Paris');
    });

    it('should contain matched results from user search', () => {
        expect(mockResultsData).toContain(mockElement.value);
    });
});
```

So far the tests pass but how can I add the 'input' event to the test? Do I always need to define a value on the input.value? How can I set it as if the user is typing 'MA' and it should test if 'Madrid' and 'Malta' is in the array?